# link to Twitter User profile Pictures not Working anymore

Tags: python, twitter

I had some embedded profile pictures in datastudio worked great until a couple of days.

I used this kind of URL:

"https://twitter.com/(userName)/profile_image?size=original"

It suddely doesn't work at all. I couldn't find any alternative either.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Since the legacy twitter.com was shut down on 15th December 2020, these URLs will no longer respond.

You will need to use the official Twitter API (either v1.1 or v2) to retrieve the User object, and get the profile image from there.

Comment: Ohh didn't know that. Thanks for the answer. Any ideas on how to construct a standard link from "screen_name" or "user_id" like the old one?